# Duck Typing and acceptance of tuples or integers in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, duck-typing

I'm working with an external (public domain) library that shows a tilemap on the screen. I'm trying to avoid using long chains of if...then...elif for input handing by using a `dict` of `lambda` statements that will adjust the viewport appropriately given the key pressed (as the key to the dict) and the current x, y position of the viewport.

The lambdas return the modified x and y coordinates in a tuple, but the function that sets the viewport (which I realize really ought to be handled with the use of `@property`, but the code already exists and would be rather painful to re-structure) takes its parameters as a separate x and y as integers.

I could make it accept a tuple by inserting the following near the top of the function:

```
if isinstance(fx,tuple):
    fx, fy = fx
```

but if we want to be super Pythonic to spite the original library developers, this won't do- the duck typing paradigm suggests that *any* object that can contain an x and a y value should be acceptable.

How would I implement this?

Comment: Actually, the change you suggests does allow any object that contains an x and y value, as long as that containment is expressed as "iterating over it will yield x, then y, and nothing more". Which is  a reasonably general interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*params` calls to the viewport function instead:

```
coordinates = lambda_mapping[key](argument)
viewport_set(*coordinates)
```

This applies the `coordinates` tuple as *separate* arguments to the `viewport_set()` function.

Demo:

```
>>> def foo(x, y):
...     print(x, y)
... 
>>> coordinates = (42, 38)
>>> foo(*coordinates)
42 38
```

Now you don't have to adjust the viewport function to take tuples as well as separate arguments.

The other alternative is to make the second coordinate a keyword argument:

```
def viewport_set(x, y=None):
    if y is None:
        # assume x is a sequence of two coordinates instead
        x, y = x
```

Comment: That's a very handy trick I'll have to remember (actually, I *did* remember it, but I thought it only worked with dicts)- but the question was more about fixing the library than making the program work with it. The (edited) way seems like the best way though- if the person using the library decides he wants to pass the function something that doesn't work, he'll just get yelled at by the interpreter as he should be.